# Validation Accuracy of Siamese CNN not increasing, stucks at 0.50

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, medical-imaging, siamese-network

I'm training a Siamese CNN model based on X-ray dataset and it gets stuck at 0.50 validation accuracy. Moreover, training and validation loss decrease while training accuracy hovers around 0.50 as well.

I think that is a error or something, but I don't know exactly what it is. Maybe use Cross-Validation could help.

Code:

[Archictecture of CNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEQ6v.png)

[Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X0G7.png)

[Training the model...(results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7OA8.png)

Comment: What is the question? If it is how to improve your accuracy, that's pretty abstract. The question should be more specific.

Comment: As far as I know, when it happens it means the neural network isn't learning, so I'd like to know if this is a mistake or if I can improve accuracy.

Comment: What is the train/val size?